# Code first windows azure connection string

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string, code-first

Here is my connection string:

```
     <add name="FollowUpDatabase" connectionString="Server=tcp:yncm4e4uxp.database.windows.net,1433;Database=[FollowUp];User ID=qwertyuiop1234567890@yncm4e4uxp;Password=XXXXXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I get this eror:

```
    Cannot open database "[FollowUp]" requested by the login. The login failed.
    Login failed for user 'qwertyuiop1234567890'.
    This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '67b05ed3-1ff7-4036-98ce-56e0d0272587'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.
```

What should I change? (Password and Login name are correct)

**EDIT**

Here is working local connection string:

```
    <add name="FollowUpDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=NET-PC;Initial Catalog=FollowUp;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; password=1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: http://sqlserverlearner.com/2012/this-session-has-been-assigned-a-tracing-id-of-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-provide-this-tracing-id-to-customer-support-when-you-need-assistance Might be of help

Comment: Have you verified you can access that database using SQL Server Management Studio? Have you also put a firewall rule (done in the Management Portal) for your IP to be able to connect to that database server?

Comment: able to connect managment studio

Comment: Have you added the database as a 'linked resource' in your web-role. You will find this tab in the management portal when viewing your cloud service.

Comment: I am use usual VS mvc4 template (no cloud templates) and publish it from downloaded profile

Comment: The differences between your azure connection string and your local connection string are that the database name is wrapped in brackets ([ ]) for the Azure connection string.  Could this be the issue?